# My new ceiling fan lighting issues

Tags: wiring, lighting

I paid a contractor to take out a light fixture and replace with a ceiling fan/light combo about 2 years ago. The fan has a remote that includes a dimmer for the light.

Here is the issue-at night, there is like a night light on it, which is not mentioned in the manual or anywhere else I’ve looked. When I turn it off from the wall switch, the light goes off, but so does the fan. I had the fan on during the day today and there was no light on.  I figure that there has to be some sort of sensor. Any suggestions?

Comment: What make and model is this fan?

Comment: From your question.  I don't see what the issue is.  The power switch controls the power to the combo unit.  You use the remote to control the fan, on/off and speed.  The remote controls the light, on/of/ and dimmer.. Remote only works when the power switch is on.

Comment: If you are implying that the remote no longer controls the light, Does it still works with the fan?  Have you try replacing the battery?